# missing SELECT keyword error from INSERT statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Alright, I've got this command:

```
INSERT INTO PHOTOS_HEADER (TC_CLOCK, DC_SCANDATE, TC_PO, DC_DATE, NC_PACKAGES) 
VALUES (:TC_CLOCK, TO_DATE(:DC_SCANDATE, :DATE_FORMAT), :TC_PO, TO_DATE(:DC_DATE, :DATE_FORMAT), :NC_PACKAGES)  
RETURNING NC_AUTOID into :OUTPUT
```

I'm running it in .NET through an `OracleCommand` object, and it runs find on our local 11g server. When this same code runs on a client site, we get this error:

> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Could it be the returning statement? Could it be `to_date`? I'm working on finding out what version of the Oracle server the client is using, but any suggestions in the mean time?

Edit: Client is running Oracle 11, same as us. Removed the returning into clause, but still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I was asked in a comment what to do if you need to work with a version of Oracle without returning.  I think that's different enough from the spirit of an answer about whether returning exists to place in its own answer.
One approach is to use the nextval function from a sequence and get the ID before the insert.

```
select sequence.nextval into :id from dual;
```

Then perform the insert.
See http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_nextval_function.htm for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely their version of oracle does not support the returning clause.  to_date in values has worked since I started playing with Oracle around Oracle 7 in 1998.
According to http://www.dba-oracle.com/plsql/t_plsql_dml.htm the returning clause was added in Oracle 9I release 2.

Comment: Do you know of an alternative way to retrieve a generated ID?